# Laravel auth check if field empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im editing my laravel auth in a way users need to activate theyr account by clicking a link in their mailbox.
My database has an extra timestamp field 'activated_at'. How can I validate if 'activated_at' is not empty. I've found te following rule to customize Auth::

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) 
{
}
```

But how should i add a rule to check for a value to be none empty?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's user provider tries to load a user by searching for exact match between user data and data passed to Auth::attempt() - see implementation of **\Illuminate\Auth\DatabaseUserProvider::retrieveByCredentials()** or **\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::retrieveByCredentials()** depending which provider you are using. Therefore it is impossible to provide **"where field not null**" constraint to **Auth::attempt()**.

You could solve that by implementing your own user provider but I don't think it's worth the effort. I suggest storing is_active flag in User model instead.

Comment: i just thought about doing an check for the activated_at in the if (auth){} if the test fails  Auth::logout(); it saves a database field over an if statement

Comment: It is an overkill. You authenticate user just to log them out immediately. Storing an additional flag in the database won't hurt you.